# To use "be" or not to use "be"

Tags: sentence-construction, modal-verbs

In some sentence such as

> "He should be hired for this job"
>
> "He should hired for this job"

When should "be" be used, or not?

Comment: "He should hired for this job" is not  grammatical. Modals (like _should_) are **always always always** followed by the base form of the next verb: _hire_ or _be_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking when to use the infinitive form of "be" necessitates too long an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many situations when we need to use a be-verb, and [passive voice](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/active-and-passive-voice) sentences like this one are one situation.

It is easiest to explain this starting with the equivalent active voice sentence:

> We should **hire** him for this job.

**we** is the subject, **hire** is what we are doing, and **him** is the object.

When you convert a sentence to passive voice, you discard the subject, more the object to the front, and replace the verb with a be-verb and a past participle:

> **He** should **be hired** for this job.